# Javascript form submitted when validation with external API fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate a form by using an external API for email validating.

Here is my form tag :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  method="post">
```

This is my JS code:

```
function validateForm() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://bpi.briteverify.com/emails.json?address=" +  $("#email").val() + "&apikey=XXXXXXXXXXX",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log('BrightVerify result : ' + data.status);
        if (data.status == 'invalid') {
            document.getElementById("checkResult").innerHTML = 'Email address is invalid!';
            console.log('Setting result to false.');
            return false;
        } 
    }); 
}
```

No matter what the API returns, the form is submitted.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: you are making an ajax call that why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return false` will prevent the form from getting submitted.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateForm(); return false;"  method="post">
```

In your `then` method, you may call `$(".form-horizontal").submit();` so that the form is submitted after the ajax call succeeds.

Answer (score -1):

validateForm function should looks like this:

```
function validateForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
}
```

and instead of `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` use `onsubmit="return validateForm(event)"`.

Form doesn't wait for ajax request and send data immediately. To stop this you should prevent default behaviour.

Comment: I've tried that and got :
Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined